# How to use probability as weight in binary logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, probability, categorical-data

I have conducted a latent class analysis which has given me the probability for each individual to be in one of two classes. The probabilities look like this

```
'''    [Class 1]     [Class2]
[ID1] 0.9971185210 0.0028814790
[ID2] 0.0344765337 0.9655234663'''
```

I want to run a binary logistic regression, to see if being in class 1 or 2 is more or less associated with outcome 1 or outcome 2. How can I create a model that is weighted by the probability of being in a class?